# ReSharper still formatting my code

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Hopefully someone can help me, because I am getting desperate.

I do not want ReSharper (or for that matter Visual Studio) to format my code, because I tend to align parts of my code to make it more readable, thus easier to understand and to maintain.

Because of this I have switched off all relevant formatting options in ReSharper (and Visual Studio). But still every once in a while my entire code is reformatted and all alignments are lost.

Has anybody encountered this as well? If so, do you happen to know what is causing this? Even better: how to prevent this?

Google was not my friend in this...

Thanks a lot,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off settings in Resharper Options

#### Environment > Editor > Editor Behavior

- Auto-format on semicolon
- Auto-format on closing brace
- Auto-insert ...

#### Code Editing > Context Actions

- Format code

Comment: Thanks, Brett. It was the last option that I overlooked. I did all the others, including the ones in the section on C#, but I missed this one...

Comment: You're welcome @PaultenBrink - if this solved your problem, please mark it as the answer  :)